# PrevProps giving same value as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `scene` component that I map to array of objects in `editor`.

And am passing the `scene` object as props to every scene, and i wanted to get the previous `scene` when i press a `button`.

But when I compare them in the console they are the same.

I used `useRef` and `useEffect` hooks to get `prevProps`

code for `editor`:

```js
const scene = {
    jsonObj: null,
  };
  const [scenes, setScenes] = useState([scene]);
  useEffect(() => {
    
  }, []);
const switchScene = (scene, prevScene) => {
    const JsonObj = canvas.setJsonObj();
    console.log(JsonObj);
    const index = scenes.indexOf(scene);
    canvas.resetEditor();
    const prevIndex = scenes.indexOf(prevScene);
    console.log(prevIndex, index);
    let cpScenes = [...scenes];
    cpScenes[prevIndex].jsonObj = JSON.stringify(JsonObj);
    setScenes(cpScenes);

    cpScenes = [...scenes];
    cpScenes[index].jsonObj = JsonObj;
    setScenes(cpScenes);

    canvas.loadJson(scene.JsonObj);

    console.log(scene);
    console.log(prevScene);
  };

return(
<div>
          {scenes.map((scene, i) => (
            <Scene
              key={i * Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}
              addText="Scene"
              onDelete={removeScene}
              scene={scene}
              switchScene={(scene, prevScene) => {
                setUpdate(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
                switchScene(scene, prevScene);
              }}
            />
          ))}
);
```

code for `scene`:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import _uniqueId from "lodash/uniqueId";

function Scene(props) {
  const id = useState(_uniqueId("sceneCmpn-"));
  const prevScene = useRef(props.scene);

  useEffect(() => {
    prevScene.current = props.scene;
  }, [props.Scene]);
  return (
    <div key={id}>
      <button
        id={id}
        onClick={() => {
          props.switchScene(props.scene, prevScene.current);
        }}
      >
        Scene
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => props.onDelete(props.scene)}
        className="btn btn-danger m-2"
      >
        remove scene
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Scene;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the way the `usePrevious` [hook](https://usehooks.com/usePrevious/) works is by returning a stale value - the `useEffect` is only called after the value is updated inside the hook (I think).

I think the problem with having `onClick` as the following:

```
onClick={() => {
  props.switchScene(props.scene, prevScene.current);
}}
```

Is that the `useEffect` will updated the `prevScene` before the click is actually handled (so it will return the same value for `props.scene, prevScene.current`).

Instead of integrating that functionality inside your component, I think you could get it to work by using the hook separately.

I tried your initial approach with a simple example with a counter:

```
function Switcher(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]); 

  const onClick = () => {
    console.log(value, ref.current);
  };

  return <button onClick={onClick}> LOG </button>;
}

export default Switcher;
```

In this case, clicking the button didn't work as expected, it showerd the same value for `value` and `previousValue`:

[image]

However this could be fixed by separating out the hook:

```
function Switcher(value) {
  const prevValue = usePrev(value);

  const onClick = () => {
    console.log(value, prevValue);
  };

  return <button onClick={onClick}> LOG </button>;
}

export default Switcher;
```

Here is the console output:

[image]

You can find the sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-field-e1tjj0?file=/src/usePrev.js)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately they are still the same. Maybe because am working with array of objects ?